# Selenium + Appium - ImplicitlyWait not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

I'm trying to automate some test for my Android app and ImplicitlyWait is not working.
I get the error the element doesn't exist right away.
If I use explicit wait, it works fine but I don't want to explicit it all the time.

```
Code:
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

# Output log
[BaseDriver] Waiting up to 30000 ms for condition
```

I'm using:

```
 - selenium-java: 3.13  
 - io.appium.java-client: 6.1.0
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use explicit wait ?

Comment: Cruise, my understand is the implicityWait would be enought as I can set it only once and it waits 30 seconds until the element shows up in the screen. I would use explicityWait when it would be really necessary.

Comment: It basically depends on what kind of application you are dealing with. If the application is very static then you may go ahead with implicit wait. Since now a days application uses Ajax , JQUERY , and lot of dynamic things, we gotta use explicit wait. So, yeah it’s required and gives much stability.

Comment: an implicit wait will also make you wait 30 seconds for every check to make sure something is not there, don't use them.  Use Explicit waits instead!

Answer (score 3):

**Implicit wait** means :

An implicit wait is to tell **WebDriver** to poll the `DOM` for a certain amount of time when trying to find an **element** or **elements** if they are not **immediately** available.

**Explicit wait** :

An explicit wait is code you define to wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code.

There are some **convenience** **methods** provided that help you write code that will **wait only as long as required** :

in this case code would be :

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
```

If you are using **explicit wait** like this, then there is no problem. But if you are using `Thread.sleep(time)`, then Note that it is a worst/extreme kind of Explicit wait which should be avoided as much as possible.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this, I voted it back up to zero, at least.  This DOES address the poster's confusion on the issue of implicit wait.  The user does not understand (seemingly) what an implicit wait is or how it works.  This answer addresses that directly.  This is a common misconception among new coders.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to implicitly wait for all elements to a fix time use below statement once in your BasePage class or Base/Parent class setUp method as is set for the life of the WebDriver object instance. So we write this statement only once.

   `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`
2. If you ever want to use explicit wait in sub class then first use this statement
   by override implicit wait to zero then use explicit wait.

   `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

**WARNING**: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times. For example setting an implicit wait of 10 seconds and an explicit wait of 15 seconds, could cause a timeout to occur after 20 seconds.

Recommendation to read official docs [here](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)